# Unable to change grub timeout in Linux Mint 18

Tags: linux, boot, grub, linux-mint

New laptop, but same habits: I want the grub timer for boot to be at 1 second instead of the 30 when selecting between windows and linux. Therefore I did the usual:

1. `vim /etc/default/grub`
2. change to `GRUB_TIMEOUT=1`
3. `update grub`

(all of the above from a root terminal, ofcourse)

However, the timer is still stuck at 30 seconds.

I've done this plenty times before, the only things that have changed are:

- New laptop (Toshiba Portege, 13.3")
- Newer version of linux mint (18 Sarah xfce)

Did I miss anything? Has there been a change between Mint 17 and 18?

---

My `/etc/defaults/grub` looks like this

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=1
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue turned out to be a classic case of [PEBCAK](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/PEBCAK). Somehow it never dawned on me that I needed to run `update-grub2` as opposed to what I did: `update-grub`. Old habbits die hard.

Comment: PS: /usr/sbin/update-grub2 is a symlink to /usr/sbin/update-grub on Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

On my Linux Mint 18 installation I had the same issue. The following settings worked for me:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=1.0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you like a timeout of X seconds try this:

GRUB_TIMEOUT=X
**GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=X**

Work for me;)

Answer (score -1):

Try "01" instead of "1".

Worked for me ;)